# My variable is not changing as it is supposed to

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing

My purpose is to change drawlines gradient each second in the form application. However it doesn't work. valueble counter " changing in label but not changing  in form paint ..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private int counter = 1;

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter++;
            if (counter >= 10)
                timer1.Stop();
            lblCountDown.Text = counter.ToString();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter = 0;

            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
            counter = new int();

            timer1.Interval = 1000; // 1 second
            timer1.Start();
            lblCountDown.Text = counter.ToString();
        } 
        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Crimson),200,200,counter ,300) ;
        }
    }
}
```

I intend to change  my drawings gradient  with time but variable is not changing when its

come to form paint... but it does change in lbl ...

help me if u can guys . dont know what to do.

Comment: You need to redraw the form, if you resize/move your form at any point during its execution does the line change?

Comment: Add `Invalidate(); Update();` in the `timer1_Tick` to repaint the form

Comment: Why do you have `private int counter = 1;` `counter = 0;` and `counter = new int();`. Isn't this too much? I think `private int counter = 0;` `counter = 0;` would be ok.

Comment: Add first line in the `timer1_Tick` event `this.Invalidate();` and see if it works?

Comment: Hassan is right: Paint will only be called if you Invalidate the Form or whatever space you want drawn fresh.

Answer (score 1):

Here, this one works. The answer is to call this.Invalidate() on form every timer tick.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int counter = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter = 1;
        timer1.Interval = 1000; // 1 second
        timer1.Start();
        lblCountDown.Text = counter.ToString();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;
        if (counter >= 10)
            timer1.Stop();
        lblCountDown.Text = counter.ToString();
        this.Invalidate();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Crimson), 200, 200, counter*10, 300);
    }
}
```

Also changed several things:

1. Event handler is set only once – to avoid multiple handlers if user clicks button several times.
2. Removed counter = new int() – no need, you have already set it to =1.
3. In Form1_Paint set x2 coordinate to counter*10 so it is easier to see the movement.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend following:

1. Use `Panel` control for Drawing and its paint event e.g. `Panel_Paint`
2. In `Timer_Tick` use `Panel.Invalidate();`
3. In the paint event **Dispose for graphic object that is `Pen`**.

Add a Panel control named `panel1` in the form. 
Keep every other control outside the panel.

**Example of Panel Paint and Timer event**:

```
 private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
  {
     using (Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.Crimson))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, 200, 200, counter, 300);                
        }
  }

 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {            
      counter++;
      if (counter >= 10)
          timer1.Stop();
      lblCountDown.Text = counter.ToString();
      panel1.Invalidate();           
  }
```